# How to convert UIView to UIImage on @2x device (iPhone 7), as good-quality as on @3x device (iPhone 7p)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

```
func shootView(view: UIView) -> UIImage{
    let imageRet : UIImage
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size , true, 0.0)
    view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    imageRet = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return imageRet
}
```

Setting the parameter Scale to 3.0 doesn't  work.
Specifically,I use the code above to convert uiview to uiimage,and it works fine on my iPhone 7.But when I send the uiimage to iPhone 7P without quality loss,it turns out the image become a little blurry.Is there any solutions for the issue?

Comment: Hi, could you please add some more description of your question?

Comment: you need to set the canvas size correctly as well.

Comment: iPhone 7 is not a @2x device

Comment: How are you "sending" the `UIImage`? Is it possible you are encoding the image to JPEG?

Comment: @iOSCuriosity FYI,[iOS Devices: Releases, Firmware, Instruction Sets, Screen Sizes](https://www.innerfence.com/howto/apple-ios-devices-dates-versions-instruction-sets)